# firebug console - what are the numbers on the right side

Tags: firebug

What are the numbers on the right side of the console?

e.g. in this image 5, 406, 12 -

[image]

Comment: That is the number of times that value presents itself. So instead of taking up a ton of real estate, the console is smart and tells you that it had 5 of this, and 406 of that. In the console.log's

Comment: does it mean that I "log" the same line 406 times?